# BoxLayout inner JPannels alignment - how can I set them to left?

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, gridbaglayout

I have been struggling with BoxLayout. I have one JPanel containing 3 inner panels. The external panel is set to BoxLayout with vertical axis, the first and second inner panels were set to set to GridBagLayout and the last one to the flowLayout (left).

The result is that first and second inner containers are aligned to the center(I guess that is is caused by the default behavior of GBL without setting the weightx). How can I align them to the left?

Do I understand correctly that anchor would work inside a cell but not align the whole grid? And that weightx would distribute the space among the cells, but not move the whole container to the left? If that is the true, should I use another component as a wrapper, or is there another way?

```
panAdv1 = new JPanel();
add(panAdv1);
panAdv1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panAdv1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

// PANEL 1 //
panel1 = new JPanel();
panAdv1.add(panel1);
panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

....

```
// PANEL 2 //

panel2 = new JPanel();
panAdv1.add(panel2);
panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

...

```
//PANEL 5 - buttons //
panel5 = new JPanel();
panAdv1.add(panel5);
panel5.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

Comment: “I guess that is caused by the default behavior of GBL without setting the weightx”  Interesting hypothesis.  Have you tried experimenting with nonzero `weightx` constraints to test that hypothesis?

Comment: You are right, I should've done that before asking the question. To my defence I have spent hours trying to make the layout work, tested anchors a read quite a bit about weightx to no avail. I have tested it this morning and it seems to do what I expected - distribute the free space, but not allow me to set the alignment of the container to the left. Is that right?

Comment: Ha, improvement! I created an empty label for the farthest right position and set it to weightx = 1.00, which cause the rest of components to align to left. Took me a while to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: (1-) @Faire, `I created an empty label...` - that is a hack and unnecessary. Use the layout managers properly. I told you how do use the BoxLayout manager properly to force the panel to be aligned to the left. Now if you do that AND set the layout of the inner panel to be a FlowLayout left aligned then you won't have a problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. What I was doing wrong was trying to change the alignment of the misaligned labels - which of course didn't work. The solution was to change the anchor setting - why it didn't work in the first place I have no idea, I must have used them wrong. So the solution was merging two gridboxes to one (which helped to align their cells) and than setting the anchor to the left where needed. The panel alignment didn't achieve much. I guess that I wasn't able to ask the question precisely enough, as the problem was not well defined and difficult to describe without help of pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Fixing Alignment Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment). The BoxLayout respects the "alignment" property of the component.

> How can I align them to the left?

The default for a JPanel would be to have the panel center aligned, so you will need to change the alignment to be left aligned.

Comment: That didn't work - the only shift was I believe inside the grid cells, it didn't change where and how the cells were aligned themselves.